# How to change the background color of a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to change the background color of a certain column in my sheet. I would hazard some code but I don't even know where to start. I know that I want to use setBackgroundColor but I don't know how to tell google sheets to apply it to a specific column.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the documentation for [`setBackground()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) explains it pretty well.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D5"); // For all of column B, use "B:B"
range.setBackground("red");
```

There are multiple ways to [get a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)). The example above uses A1 notation. You can also define its dimensions by defining the top left-most cell and then the [number of rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows).

```
var columnB = sheet.getRange(
  1, // Row 1
  2, // Column 2 (B)
  sheet.getMaxRows() // Number of rows
);
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason the documentation for setBackground was nowhere to be found when I googled it... 

How can I use an integer instead of a letter to select the column?

Comment: @user2603186 I've expanded my answer to describe how that can be done. Hope it helps.